# Find two values in two columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I'm implementing OOP PHP with prepared statements on my website.

I have the following table name, "table":

| rowID | id1 | id2 | name1 | name2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 55 | 56 | name55 | name56 |
| 2 | 55 | 60 | name55 | name60 |
| 3 | 54 | 55 | name54 | name55 |

I have two user-defined IDs that need to be matched with the id1 or id2 columns.

Note that id1 < id2 which means that if the user-defined values are id1 > id2, the match will not be found. That's my problem. I have trouble checking whether the combination id1 and id2 is found, regardless if id1 > id2 or id1 < id2.

How do I do that with placeholders?

The PHP code:

```
public function getMatch($id, $id2)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id1 = ? AND id2 = ?";
        $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute([$id, $id2]);
        $outputs = $stmt->fetchAll();
        
         foreach ($outputs as $output) {
            echo $output["name1"];
            echo $output["name2"];
        }  
        
    }
```

Handling the user-defined IDs:

```
    $Match = new getMatch();
    $Match->getMatch($input1, $input2);
```

If input1=id1=56 and input2=id2=55, no match will be found, even though id1=55 and id2=56 exist.

Right now I'm just avoiding the problem with this "solution":

```
    $Match->getMatch($input1, $input2);
    $Match->getMatch($input2, $input1);
```

One of them will always work while the other returns null. But I need it done more elegantly.

Comment: You could update your query to include the logic of what the second call to getMatch does. Thus `WHERE case1 OR case2;`

Comment: Hi Remy, thanks for your suggestion. I already did that, and it works, but I'm unhappy with that solution, too:

$a = $id1;
    $b = $id2;
    if($a > $b) {
        $a = $id2;
        $b = $id1;
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the operator `IN` like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE (?, ?) IN ((id1, id2), (id2, id1))
```

Comment: Note that (irritatingly) MySQL cannot optimise this.

Comment: @Strawberry What does that mean? Does it have any practical consequences?

Comment: It means that writing it out longhand will be more optimal

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE (?, ?) IN ((id1, id2), (id2, id1))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It was already suggested by forpas, and is a working solution.